# Django DeleteView form loads, but does not delete item

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I tried implementing deleteview, however, while the form and page loads and the buttons are fine and redirects me since I put an action within the form, it does not delete the data at the end. I have been stuck at this for hours, please help me!

**Competencies model**

```
class Competencies(models.Model): 
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Profile, blank = False, null = True, on_delete = models.SET_NULL)
    competency_category = models.ForeignKey(competency_category, blank = False, null = True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
                .
                .

    def __str__(self):
        return self.summary
```

**Views.py - DeleteView class**

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView, DeleteView
class Competencies_Delete(DeleteView):
    model = Competencies
    template_name = 'GnC/HuNet_DeleteDGC.html'

    def get_object(self):
        id = self.kwargs.get("pk")
        return get_object_or_404(Competencies, id = id)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('GnC:User_GnC')
```

**Html file that onclick 'Delete', allows deletion**

```
{%for competencies in Personal_competencies_list%}
<tr>
    <td><a href = '../allusers/{{competencies.id}}/DeleteC'>Delete</a></td>

</tr>
{%endfor%}
```

**HuNet_DeleteDGC.html**

```
{%extends 'utilitypage.html'%}
{%block content%}

<form action="{% url 'GnC:User_GnC'%}" method='POST'>
    {%csrf_token%}
    <h4>Do you want to delete "{{object.summary}}"?</h4>
    <p><input type ='submit' value = 'Confirm'></p>
    <p><a href="{% url 'GnC:User_GnC'%}">Cancel</a></p>
</form>

{%endblock%}
```

**urls.py**

```
app_name = 'GnC'
urlpatterns = [
path('allusers/<int:pk>/DeleteC', views.Competencies_Delete.as_view(), name ="Delete_User_Competencies")
]
```

Comment: Should't th8is be `type="submit"`, etc. Please first fix the HTML of the template.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Hi, yes you are right, I have changed it to ```<input type="submit" value="Confirm">```, but still does not work ):

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, my `<form action="{% url 'GnC:User_GnC'%}" method='POST'>` should have been `<form action="" method='POST'>`